# Triangle cropping between a 2D triangle and square

Tags: geometry, polygon, intersection, triangulation

I am trying to implement a decal mesh generator as described here: http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/06/how-to-project-decals/. The blog suggests an algorithm for triangulation of the intersection polygon between a triangle and square:

> First, we can start with one border at a time. Let's pick the left
>   border. To crop the triangle, we start by marking every vertex in
>   violation of the rule -- in this case, the leftmost one. Then we look
>   at every line between a marked vertex and an unmarked vertex, and add
>   a vertex at the point at which it crosses the border.
>
> We can then simply remove the marked vertex (or vertices), and move
>   onto the next border.
>
> Once we've checked all the borders, we have a cropped triangle!

I attempted this algorithm on paper and it doesn't seem like its covering all cases. It seems that its description is missing some critical detail that I have missed. Could someone post a pseudo code implementation?

EDIT: To be more specific, the part that I am unclear on is how the algorithm is able to determine the right "cut" between (black line) [image]

and

[image]

When there are multiple choices.

Secondly why does the algorithm not make a cut between the top point of polygon and the bottom left point in picture 2? The algorithm states that "we look
at every line between a marked vertex and an unmarked vertex, and add
a vertex at the point at which it crosses the border", isnt the bottom left point an unmarked vertex?

Answer (score 1):

A reliable way to derive the algorithm is to consider the problem of intersecting a triangle and a half-plane.

First determine if the vertices are in or out of the half plane. This leads to 8 configurations: one such that the whole triangle is discarded, one such that it is left unchanged, three such that it is cropped to a quadrilateral and three such that it is cropped to another triangle.

In the case of a quadrilateral, you split it in two via a diagonal.

After this step, you have 0, 1 or 2 triangles remaining, and you just repeat the operation with the next clipping half-plane on each of them. Bulletproof.

[image]

---

If the triangles are large and are often clipped on several sides (which I doubt), you can consider intersecting with two half-planes forming a stripe at a time. There are 27 cases and the output is made of from 0 to 3 sub-triangles. This can save a few comparisons and intersection computations.

Direct clipping by a rectangle seems complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I eventually decided to dig down into the graphics pipeline resources because I imagine clipping a triangle against a rectangle would be a very common operation. So after lots of digging I found Sutherland–Hodgman poly clipping algorithm and implemented it. It seems to me that the post is describing SH but left out critical details... I think I will leave my question as is in hope that some one would correct me.

Comment: My solution can be made more efficient than straight SH. Also note that it is not pure SH as it only generates triangles, not polygons, which was made on purpose.

Comment: Could you elaborate? My understanding of SH is that its basically 4 triangle/quad - plane cuts, but instead of storing the triangles it just stores the vertices. Which seems to me be very similar to your suggestion.

Comment: SH handles general polygons, not just triangles.

Comment: Im not sure how the fact that SH handles general polygon make it slower. Seems to me that keeping the intermediary result between each plane clip as a polygon saves vertices to be considered compared to keeping as individual triangles.